# F# Type Provider Set Optional Field With Required Parameter, Getting a "Specified Method is not supported" error

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-data, fsharp.data.typeproviders

I'm trying to build a type provider for Bloomberg (they provide schema xml files that describe the types). I'm able to generate types that look like the following class:

```
type Example(x: option<int>) as self =
    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable X: option<int>

    do
        self.X <- x

    member this.GetX with get() = self.X
```

The problem is that this requires you to instantiate the example type as follows:

```
Example(Some 1)
```

Ideally I would prefer to instantiate it as like the XmlProvider choice type:

```
type Example(x: int) as self =
    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable X: option<int>

    do
        self.X <- Some x

    member this.GetX with get() = self.X

let example = Example(1)
```

When I attempt doing this:

```
let some =
    FSharpType.GetUnionCases(field.FieldType)
    |> Array.filter (fun x -> x.Name = "Some")
    |> Array.exactlyOne
let arg' = Expr.NewUnionCase(some, arg)
let setValue = Expr.FieldSet(this, field, arg')
```

I get the following error:

"Specified method is not supported."

I can successfully generate the first type using this:'

```
let setValue = Expr.FieldSet(this, field, arg)
```

The full source code is available here: https://github.com/alphaarchitect/BloombergProvider/blob/main/src/BloombergProvider.DesignTime/BloombergProvider.DesignTime.fs#L457

Any ideas?

///Edit

The entire code block is from this:

```
es
|> Result.mapError (fun xs -> ChoiceError.Element(c.Name, xs))
|> Result.map (fun xs ->
    xs
    |> List.iter (fun (_, field) ->
        let parameter = ProvidedParameter(field.Name, field.FieldType)
        providedChoiceType.AddMember
        <| ProvidedConstructor(
            [parameter],
            invokeCode =
                fun args ->
                    match args with
                    | this :: [arg] ->
                        let setValue = Expr.FieldSet(this, field, arg)
                        let enumField = Expr.FieldSet(this, enumField, Expr.FieldGet(enum.GetField(field.Name)))
                        Expr.Sequential(enumField, setValue)
                    | _ -> failwith "wrong ctor parameters"))
    {
        Enum = enum
        Object = providedChoiceType
    }))
```

to this:

```
es
|> Result.mapError (fun xs -> ChoiceError.Element(c.Name, xs))
|> Result.map (fun xs ->
    xs
    |> List.iter (fun (type', field) ->
        let parameter = ProvidedParameter(field.Name, type')
        providedChoiceType.AddMember
        <| ProvidedConstructor(
            [parameter],
            invokeCode =
                fun args ->
                    match args with
                    | this :: [arg] ->
                        let some =
                            FSharpType.GetUnionCases(field.FieldType)
                            |> Array.filter (fun x -> x.Name = "Some")
                            |> Array.exactlyOne
                        let arg' = Expr.NewUnionCase(some, arg)
                        let setValue = Expr.FieldSet(this, field, arg')
                        let enumField = Expr.FieldSet(this, enumField, Expr.FieldGet(enum.GetField(field.Name)))
                        Expr.Sequential(enumField, setValue)
                    | _ -> failwith "wrong ctor parameters"))
    {
        Enum = enum
        Object = providedChoiceType
    }))
```

[image: Specified method is not supported.]

The error occurs when you try to instantiate the type provider.

Running and evaluating the code works correctly in the quotation evaluator.

Comment: I tried to reproduce what you're seeing two different ways. First, I tried to clone and compile your repository, but wasn't sure how to trigger the error. Then, I tried using just the code in your question and the [F# Quotations Evaluator](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator/), but that didn't generate any error. Instead, I was successfully able to set the value of the `Example.X` field. So, as it stands, I don't think there's enough information in your question to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you Brian, I added a screenshot showing the error. There are two solutions files in the repository, the first one creates the type provider and the second one has the tests. The test solutions file is the one that shows the error. I think the error may be happening somewhere in the type providers sdk, my thinking is that because unions don't work in C# and the type provider generates C# style classes, the NewUnionCase code may be generating invalid IL. I tried creating a standalone function to do this as well, but got the same error. Let me know what additional detail I could provide.

Comment: I should also note that the code does make it past the field set before generating the error. It appears to happen once I try to add the object to the assembly.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but it may help you if you cannot figure out how to get this to work. In general, I think that building type providers is easier if you do not try to do a "lot of coding" in the provided methods and constructors.

In your approach, you have a type that inherits from `obj` and so you have to generate a lot of code to store data in fields. In contrast, the JSON provider types inherit from `JsonValue` which does all the storing for them - so they have to do relatively little. For example, say you want to generate something like:

```
type Example(x: int, y:string) as self =
  [<DefaultValue>] val mutable X: option<int>
  [<DefaultValue>] val mutable Y: option<string>
  do
    self.X <- Some x
    self.Y <- Some y
member this.GetX = self.X
member this.GetY = self.Y
```

It may be easier to define a base class which is essentially a dictionary an then generate a class inheriting from this:

```
type DataClass() = 
  let d = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<_, _>()
  member x.SetSome(s, v) = d.[s] <- Some v
  member x.Get<'T>(s) = d.[s] |> Option.map (fun v -> unbox<'T> v)

type Example(x: int, y:string) =
  inherit DataClass() 
  do
    base.SetSome("x", box x)
    base.SetSome("y", box y)
  member this.GetX = base.Get<int>("x")
  member this.GetY = base.Get<string>("y")
```

This way, the only kind of provided code that you have to write is method calls, which is generally easier to do - and possibly less error-prone.

Comment: Thank you, Tomas, great advice.